# How do i have my var errorMessage output whether to use field or fields depending on how many fields are left blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Trying to have field/fields displayed depending if 1 or more fields are missing in a Jquery form validation. Here is my code:

```
function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var errorMessage = "";
    var fieldMissing = "";

    if ($("#email").val() == "") {
        fieldMissing += "<br>Email";
    }

    if ($("#phone").val() == "") {
        fieldMissing += "<br>Telephone";
    }

    if ($("#password").val() == "") {
        fieldMissing += "<br>Password";
    }

    if ($("#passwordConfirm").val() == "") {
        fieldMissing += "<br>Confirm Password";
    }

    if (fieldMissing != "") {
        errorMessage += "<p>The following field(s) are missing:</p>" + fieldMissing;
    }

    if (fieldMissing > 2)

    if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Your email address is not valid</p>";
    }

    if ($.isNumeric($("#phone").val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Your phone number is not numeric</p>"
    }

    if ($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirm").val()) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Your passwords do not match</p>";
    }

    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

Can someone please help me out? Just trying to figure this out.

Comment: Do you know [Jquery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)?

Comment: @gabriel, no i do not. I'm actually in the learning process , just trying to do something more advanced, that I may learn/understand better for myself on how I would implement what i'm trying to do

Comment: When i say field/fields i mean in my appended outputs. so for ex: if i left out phone#, and email it would say "fields" if i just left out 1 field for it to say "field"

Comment: Could you change your question to say what you're expecting exactly and what error's you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (fieldMissing > 2) {` condition is missing a closing `}` bracket.  It also seems unnecessary.  Just remove the whole block.

Comment: actually i was just thinking maybe that's what i'm supposed to do, however I wasn't sure if the function would recognize the value due to me not putting in a var to check how many fields exist...

Comment: Actually what is the point of your fieldMissing > 2 condition?

Comment: thank you, how would I go about doing that? would it be `if (fieldMissing != "" + fieldMissing >2)?

Comment: Your fieldMissing variable is a string, not an int.  So fieldMissing > 2 is not a valid expression.

Comment: I apologize for the question not being clear. I want to change the var errorMessage to either field or fields depending on how many field(s) are missing. so if only missing one field i want the errorMessage var to say " the following field is missing" else it would say "the following fields are missing

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable (errorCount) to count the number of errors.

```
function isEmail(email) {  
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    var errorMessage = "";
    var fieldMissing = "";
    var errorCount = 0;

    if ($("#email").val() == "") {
        errorCount = errorCount  + 1;
        fieldMissing += "<br>Email";
    }

    if ($("#phone").val() == "") {
        errorCount = errorCount  + 1;
        fieldMissing += "<br>Telephone";
    }

    if ($("#password").val() == "") {
        errorCount = errorCount  + 1;
        fieldMissing += "<br>Password";
    }

    if ($("#passwordConfirm").val() == "") {
        errorCount = errorCount  + 1;
        fieldMissing += "<br>Confirm Password";
    }

    if (fieldMissing != "") {
        errorCount = errorCount  + 1;
        errorMessage += "<p>The following field(s) are missing:</p>" + fieldMissing;
    }

    if (errorCount > 2) {
        errorMessage += "Fields errors"
    } else if (errorCount == 1){
        errorMessage += "Field error"
    }


    if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Your email address is not valid</p>";
    }

    if ($.isNumeric($("#phone").val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Your phone number is not numeric</p>"
    }

    if ($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirm").val()) {    
        errorMessage += "<p>Your passwords do not match</p>";
    }

    alert(errorMessage);

});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer more?

Comment: @barry doyle, I apologize for the question not being clear. I want to change the var errorMessage to either field or fields depending on how many field(s) are missing. so if only missing one field i want the errorMessage var to say " the following field is missing" else it would say "the following fields are missing